I need help to make my code run more efficiently. This is for a DIscord bot that constantly reads a log file
A little Background information, I created a Discord bot, it does what I want it to do, but I need to reduce the resource load from reading a log file constantly. I am not a programmer by trade. I just think this fun mess with, but I can't seem to figure out a better way that actually works.
My problem code is as follows.

@bot.event
async def stream_terminal_log():
    current_log = await getcurrent_log()
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("Terminal stream Started")
    async with aiofiles.open(current_log, mode='r', buffering=4192 * 16) as datastream:
        while True:
            async for line in datastream:
                check the line for lots for different things

running this as shown causes the bot process to run Very High @ about 17-20% CPU usage
I have it started in the @onready as shown below.

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Connected to Discord!")
    guild = await bot.fetch_guild(XXXXXXXXXXXXX)
    await bot.tree.sync(guild=guild)
    print("Slash commands synced!")
    await bot.tree.sync()
    await asyncio.gather(every_ten(), stream_terminal_log())


asyncio.gather was the only way I could get it to run without being a blocker.
Again, not a programmer by trade. I had an idea and just mess with it till it works. This works, but not efficiently.
I've tried reading lines, and attempted to read end of file, but reverted back to my original code as I couldn't get anything to work.
Developing it in PyCharm.

@itprorh66 They will need to provide more code on code review. The last line in the first block of code is not code and would have to be replaced by real code, otherwise the question will be closed as off-topic due to Missing Code Context.

The performance problem with your code is likely hidden behind the "check the line for lots for different things" removal. The code you have provided is unlikely to have the performance issue you are indicating. You could post on Code Review as is however some users less experienced with Python are likely to close the question.
